# Create a String from the part of the vector

Tags: rust

I want to create a String from the part of the vector.

My code:

```
fn main() {
    let  v = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    let mut res = String::new(); // expect to have "cd"
    let start_pos: usize = 2;
    for i in start_pos..v.len() {
        res.push(v[i]);
    }
    println!("{}", res); // "cd"
}
```

Is it possible to do the same shorter?

Comment: This isn't [codegolf.se], so we prefer "better" to "shorter" (sometimes shorter is better, sometimes not).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could convert the `Vec` into an iterator, and write this in fluent style.

```rs
fn main() {
    let  v = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    let res : String = v
        .into_iter()
        .skip(2)
        .collect();
    println!("{}", res); // "cd"
}
```

Instead of `skip(2)` on the iterator, you could convert a slice of the `Vec`:

```
fn main() {
    let  v = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    let res : String = v[2..]
        .into_iter()
        .collect();
    println!("{}", res); // "cd"
}
```

I find this very readable, and it generates fast code. One advantage it has is that `res` no longer needs to be `mut`, but can be a static single assignment. To achieve that with the loop implementation, you would need to move the loop into a helper, or “phi,” function.

In real-world code, a container like `v`, whose data are compile-time constants and never modified, would be a `const` or `static` array, not a `Vec`.

Recall that a Rust `String` holds UTF-8 bytes, not an array of UCS-4 `char`. There’s a function to move a `Vec<u8>` that holds valid UTF-8 bytes into a `String`: [`String::from_utf8`.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8)  It’s likely that your input will be in UTF-8 as well, so if you can avoid the overhead of converting between UCS-4 and UTF-8 or vice versa, that will be far more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, thats what i need